# custom checkbox hide background and border

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors

[image: checkbox problem gif]
When I mark the lower checkboxes then the upper one above them and hover the lower checked checkboxes ones, then they hidden border and background, better watch gif.
I don't understand what i'm doing wrong with selectors. Added codepen.
[`codepen`](https://codepen.io/mariooooo/pen/yLBVMMW)

Comment: links to codepen must be accompanied with the code in the question itself, don't just mark the link as code to get around this requirement

Answer (score 1):

In `.cbx span:first-child:before` remove `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML code:
<label for="defaultCheckbox" class="si si-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="defaultCheckbox" />
  <span class="si-label">Default checkbox state</span>
</label>

<label for="checkedCheckbox" class="si si-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkedCheckbox" checked />
  <span class="si-label">Checked checkbox state</span>
</label>



CSS FOR DEFAULT STATE:
.si.si-checkbox .si-label::before {
  border-radius: var(--border-size-checkmark);
}

/* checkbox checkmark */
.si.si-checkbox .si-label::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 18px;
  border-width: 0 var(--border-size-checkmark) var(--border-size-checkmark) 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent var(--color-active) var(--color-active) transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotate-default)) scale(0);
}



CSS FOR CHECKED STATE:

/* checkbox square */
.si.si-checkbox > input:checked + .si-label::before {
  transform: rotate(var(--rotate-active)) scale(0);
}

/* checkmark */
.si.si-checkbox > input:checked + .si-label::after {
  left: 8px;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotate-active)) scale(1);
}
```